# Firefox Addon Builder Alternative

Tags: javascript, firefox, builder

Is there any firefox addon builder alternative 
instead of using notepad++ and the online builder by mozilla ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla [Howto](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

You don't have other alternatives.